# Python coordinates out of range for polygon

Tags: python, list, numpy, parsing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working on a script whos job is to comb through a CSV file full of pixel values. I have used a json file to find dimensions of a polygon I preannotated and I am trying to calculate a value for the average pixels within that object. the pixel_temperature list is a [512][640] same as the dimensions of the image. I am using skimage's polygon functions to calculate all of the pixels within the points of my polygon

```
# Find all points within polygon
                        r = np.array([y1, y2, y3, y4])
                        c = np.array([x1, x2, x3, x4])
                        x_axis, y_axis = draw.polygon(r, c)
```

NOTE: x and y in my JSON and mixed up that is why im stating y's first

This produces two nparrays (x_axis, y_axis) of equal lengths (tested this with random points being selected, also they are coordinates so need to come in pairs) I am trying to iterate through these two lists simultaneously and then calculate my value. This works for most of my polygons but I randomly hit a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "u-valueV2.py", line 232, in <module>
    main()
  File "u-valueV2.py", line 228, in main
    parseJSON(jsonFilePath)
  File "u-valueV2.py", line 113, in parseJSON
    average_u_value = parseCSVPolygon(csvFilePath, csvFileName[0], x_axis, y_axis)
  File "u-valueV2.py", line 197, in parseCSVPolygon
    total += u_value_calculation(emissivity, pixel_temperature[x[item]][y[item]])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Since the lists are of equal length and my pixel_temp list holds all 512 by 640 values I am not understanding why I am getting this error.

The error is referring to this block within my parseCSVPolygon function

```
fileName += ".csv"
path = csvFilePath + '/' + fileName
with open(path) as read_csv:
    csvData = csv.reader(read_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')  # Seperated by comma (hence csv)
    for i, data in enumerate(csvData):  # i holds the index and increments each loop while data holds cells value
        length = len(data)
        if (length == 0):  # Incase the length of a row is 0 (empty cells)
            continue
        else:
            index = length - 1  # Extract the last data point in the row
        if (i == 2):
            emissivity = float(data[index])
            #print(emissivity)
        if (i >= 10):
            pixel_temperature.append(data[1:])  # Pixel temperature now holds 512 indexes. Each index

#TODO: Figure out how to calculate the doors u-value (or Polygons)
for item in range(len(y)):
    total += u_value_calculation(emissivity, pixel_temperature[x[item]][y[item]])
average = total / (len(x) * len(y))
return average
```

I am puzzled as to the source of this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: use `print()` to check value in `item`, `x[item]`, `y[item]` , and `pixel_temperature[x[item]][y[item]]` - it seem one of this value is bigger then size of your data - and it gives error `"IndexError: list index out of range"`. Maybe your data has size `640x512` instead of `512x640`. It is very popular to use `[y,x]` instead of `[x,y]` in array/matrix.

Comment: You seem to be right. That is so odd.. I was using supervisely to annotate some images and although the documentation says x,y the data itself seems like it is in y,x... I seem to be running into this issue frequently